# Visual Studio Hangs After Adding Post-Build-Event

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2015, post-build-event, ilmerge

I am following [this tutorial](https://iandotnet.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/merge-exe-and-dll-into-one-using-ilmerge-c/) which explains how to attached post-build events to a project.

This is my `.bat` file (tried with and without the `D:` `rem`d out):

```
CMD
ECHO parameter=%1
CD %1
rem D:
COPY WpfFileDeleter.exe temp.exe
"..\..\ILMerge.exe" /out:"WpfFileDeleter.exe" "temp.exe" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.ExtendedLinguisticServices.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Sensors.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.ShellExtensions.dll"
DEL temp.exe
```

And I also added this `ILMerge.exe.config` as per the tutorial (I was getting  the `Unresolved assembly reference not allowed` error):

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

But when I build my project in VS it just hangs with this message in `Output`:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: WpfFileDeleter, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

I can see that some files have been copied to `bin/debug`, such as the `.dlls` I specified and `temp.exe`, but any `WpfFileDeleter.exe`s cannot be run properly as it has not been merged properly.

My question is **How can I debug this issue?** Is there some way of outputting the results of ILMerge or the build process so that I can see where it is going wrong?

Comment: Hangs like this are almost always caused by wonky anti-malware.  It never likes seeing executable files appear from seemingly nowhere.  If you use Avast, particularly prone to scans that hang forever, then plan to get rid of it asap.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment! I don't have anything like that installed but will remember that for the future. See my answer for how I resolved the issue - not sure why the linked tutorial didn't include this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by specifying the `targetFramework` when calling `ILMerge` in the batch file:

```
"..\..\ILMerge.exe" /out:"WpfFileDeleter.exe" /targetPlatform:"v4" "temp.exe" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.ExtendedLinguisticServices.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Sensors.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.ShellExtensions.dll"
```